# negated is.na() combined with which() gives inconsistent results

Tags: r

See inconsistent behaviour with R version 4.1.1 (RStudio 1.4.1717):

```
> !(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> (is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> !(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))) %>% which()
[1] FALSE FALSE
> (is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))) %>% which()
[1] 1 4
```

In one case which() beautifully identifies the indices of TRUE values in a vector, in the other (when using !), it doesn't. Anyone with an explanation for this or did I find a bug?

Comment: I think it's down to operator precedence.  `!(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))) %>% which()` is probably doing `!{(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))) %>% which()}`, not `{!(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))} %>% which()` (using `{` and `}` to show grouping, not correct syntax).  `(!(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))) %>% which()` gives `2, 3`, which seems to be what you're expecting.

Comment: Putting it another way, it's the difference between `!which(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))` and 
`which(!is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)))`

Comment: from `?which`, `seq_along(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))[!is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA)) & c(NA, 4, 56, NA)]
[1] 2 3`, which in your's is returned 'FALSE FALSE'.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to track down such issues is the {lobstr} package. It shows each called function of an expression / code block and in which order/nesting these are called.

As you can see, the `!` operator is called AFTER which got applied to the result is `is.na`, hence both TRUEs.

```
lobstr::ast(!(is.na(c(NA, 4, 56, NA))) %>% which())
#> █─`!` 
#> └─█─`%>%` 
#>   ├─█─`(` 
#>   │ └─█─is.na 
#>   │   └─█─c 
#>   │     ├─NA 
#>   │     ├─4 
#>   │     ├─56 
#>   │     └─NA 
#>   └─█─which
```

You can also have a look at `?Syntax` where operator precedence as evaluated by R is shown.